# Definition of TYPE?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
array DWORD 10,20,30,40,50
sum DWORD 0

.code
main PROC

mov EDI,offset array
mov ECX,5
mov EAX,0
HERE:

add eax,[edi]
add edi,TYPE array
dec ecx
jnz HERE

mov sum,eax

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

What does TYPE mean inside the loop line: edi, TYPE array?
Is it the **TYPE** of variable we are using in the array that it replaces?

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

`TYPE` return the size, in bytes, of the "representing" type of a data structure (such an array).
`SIZEOF` return the size, in bytes, of a data structure.
`LENGTHOF` returns the number of "elements" in a data structure.

Note that these operators can be applied either to types (e.g. `BYTE`) or to labels (e.g. `TYPE myLabel`).
The result can be different for same data structures (e.g. records).

Precise meaning is given made below.

Note that there is similarly named operator `.TYPE` that can be used in macros to return a byte bitfield containing information about an expression (e.g. it names a register).
This is what is presented by the poorly written MASM documentation in the MSDN.

There is a [MASM 6.1 reference document here](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf), I don't know how much authoritative it is but all of this answer is based on it.

---

**Primitives**

That document lists `TYPE` as an operator similar to `SIZEOF`

> The `SIZEOF` and `TYPE` operators, when applied to a **type**, return the size of an integer of that type.
>
> The size attribute associated with each data type is:
>
> ```
> Data Type       Bytes
>   BYTE, SBYTE     1
>   WORD, SWORD     2
>   DWORD, SDWORD   4
>   FWORD           6
>   QWORD           8
>   TBYTE           10
> ```

Here the operators are applied to a type, I believe it's possible to apply them to labels associated with primitives, resulting in the same output.

**Arrays**

For an array the difference between `SIZEOF` and `TYPE` (and `LENGTHOF`) becomes clear:

> The `LENGTHOF` operator returns the number of elements in the array. The `SIZEOF` operator returns
>   the number of bytes used by the initializers in the array definition. `TYPE` returns the size of the
>   elements of the array. The following examples illustrate these operators:
>
> ```
> array WORD 40 DUP (5)
>
> larray EQU LENGTHOF array   ; 40 elements
> sarray EQU SIZEOF array     ; 80 bytes
> tarray EQU TYPE array       ; 2 bytes per element
> ```

In this case, the operators are used with labels.

**Strings**

For String, it suffices to recall that Strings are arrays of bytes.

**Structures**

For Structures, the concept is similar to the arrays': `TYPE` is size of the structure while `SIZEOF` is the size of the all the structure objects associated with the label (MASM consider a thing like `myLabel db 1, 2, 3` as being three bytes associated with `myLabel`):

> The size of a structure determined by `SIZEOF` is the offset of the last field, plus the size of the last
>   field, plus any padding required for proper alignment.
>
> ```
> INFO STRUCT
>  buffer BYTE 100 DUP (?)
>  crlf BYTE 13, 10
>  query BYTE 'Filename: '
>  endmark BYTE 36
>  drives DISKDRIVES <0, 1, 1>
> INFO ENDS
>
> ;One struct
> info1 INFO { , , 'Dir' }
>
> ;Three structs for this label
> lotsof INFO { , , 'file1', , {0,0,0} },
>             { , , 'file2', , {0,0,1} },
>             { , , 'file3', , {0,0,2} }
>
> sinfo1 EQU SIZEOF info1    ; 116 = number of bytes in initializers
> linfo1 EQU LENGTHOF info1  ; 1 = number of items
> tinfo1 EQU TYPE info1      ; 116 = same as size
>
> slotsof EQU SIZEOF lotsof   ; 116 * 3 = number of bytes in initializers
> llotsof EQU LENGTHOF lotsof ; 3 = number of items
> tlotsof EQU TYPE lotsof     ; 116 = same as size for structure
>  ; of type INFO
> ```

In this case, the operators are used with labels.

**Unions**

For Unions, something very similar happens:

> The size of a union determined by `SIZEOF` is the size of the longest field plus any padding required.
>   The length of a union variable determined by `LENGTHOF` equals the number of initializers defined
>   inside angle brackets or curly braces. `TYPE` returns a value indicating the type of the longest field.
>
> ```
> DWB UNION
>  d DWORD ?
>  w WORD ?
>  b BYTE ?
> DWB ENDS
>
> num DWB {0FFFFh}
> array DWB (100 / SIZEOF DWB) DUP ({0})
>
> snum EQU SIZEOF num       ; = 4
> lnum EQU LENGTHOF num     ; = 1
> tnum EQU TYPE num         ; = 4
>
> sarray EQU SIZEOF array   ; = 100 (4*25)
> larray EQU LENGTHOF array ; = 25
> tarray EQU TYPE array     ; = 4
> ```

In this case, the operators are used with labels.

**Records**

Records are bytes, words, or doublewords in which the individual bits or groups of bits are considered fields.
<sup>Quoted from the manual, but not formatted as a quote intentionally.</sup>

> The `SIZEOF` and `TYPE` operators applied to a record name return the number of bytes used by the
>   record. `SIZEOF` returns the number of bytes a record variable occupies. You cannot use `LENGTHOF`
>   with a record declaration, but you can use it with defined record variables. `LENGTHOF` returns the
>   number of records in an array of records, or 1 for a single record variable. The following example
>   illustrates these points.

```
; Record definition
; 9 bits stored in 2 bytes
RGBCOLOR RECORD red:3, green:3, blue:3
```

> ```
>  mov ax, RGBCOLOR              ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 01FFh"
>  ; mov ax, LENGTHOF RGBCOLOR   ; Illegal since LENGTHOF can
>                                ; apply only to data label
>  mov ax, SIZEOF RGBCOLOR       ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 2"
>  mov ax, TYPE RGBCOLOR         ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 2"
>
> ; Record instance
> ; 8 bits stored in 1 byte
> RGBCOLOR2 RECORD red:3, green:3, blue:2
> rgb RGBCOLOR2 <1, 1, 1> ; Initialize to 00100101y
>
>  mov ax, RGBCOLOR2     ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 00FFh"
>  mov ax, LENGTHOF rgb  ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 1"
>  mov ax, SIZEOF rgb    ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 1"
>  mov ax, TYPE rgb      ; Equivalent to "mov ax, 1"
> ```

Here there is a little asymmetry when using the operators with labels and with types.

---

**`.TYPE` as an operator for macros**

This operator is the old version of `OPATTR` and returns a byte with the following content:

```
Bit    Set If expression
0      References a code label
1      Is a memory variable or has a relocatable data label
2      Is an immediate value
3      Uses direct memory addressing
4      Is a register value
5      References no undefined symbols and is without error
6      Is relative to SS
7      References an external label
```

This has a taste of metaprogramming and it is normally used to optimise the code generated with macros.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [TYPE operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-type), which will return the type of the expression it is used with (in this particular case, `array`)

For further reference: [MASM operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/assembler/masm/operators-reference)